# Updating objects with getline doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, class, object, cin, getline

I'm having odd behavior when creating and using a class. 

I create multiple instances of that class, sequentially - and then I create a few temp variables to prompt the user to enter some data, then i use basic mututaor functions and pass the data to the parts of the object. I do this for the first item, then the second, etc. 

What happens when the declarations of those personalData elements are sequential then for some reason the cin/getline statements skip over some and i can't enter all the data correctly. When i spread them out between statements have one object created then the input from the user then updates, then the next object it works better but still not in 100% of the cases. Lastly i found that creating different variables for inputting data  - my temp variables also resolves the problem but that seems strange to have to create a dozen variables when i should be able to input data/update existing ones?

```
class personalData
{
private:
    string name;
    string address;
    int phone;
    int age;
public:
    void setname(string);
    void setadress(string);
    void setphone(int);
    void setage(int);
    string getname()const;
    string getadress()const;
    int getage()const;
    int getphone()const;
};

void personalData::setname(string n)
{ name=n; }
void personalData::setadress(string a)
{ address=a; }
void personalData::setphone(int p)
{ phone=p;}
void personalData::setage(int ag)
{age=ag;}

string personalData::getname()const
{return name;}
string personalData::getadress()const
{return address;}
int personalData::getage()const
{return age;}
int  personalData ::getphone()const
{return phone;}


int main()
{
personalData my;
personalData friendd;
personalData family; 

string n;
string a;
int p;
int g;

cout<<"enter your name";
getline(cin,n);
cout<<"enter your address:";
getline(cin,a);
cout<<"enter your phone:";
cin>>p;
cout<<"enter your age";
cin>>g; 

my.setname(n);
my.setadress(a);
my.setphone(p);
my.setage(g);   

cout<<"enter your friend's name";
getline(cin,n);
cout<<"enter your friend's address:";
getline(cin,a);
cout<<"enter your friend's phone:";
cin>>p; 
cout<<"enter your friend's age";
cin>>g;

 friendd.setname(n);
 friendd.setadress(a);
 friendd.setphone(p);
 friendd.setage(g);


cout<<"enter your family member's name";
getline(cin,n);
cout<<"enter your family member's address:";
getline(cin,a);
cout<<"enter your family member's phone:";
cin>>p; 
cout<<"enter your family member's age";
cin>>g;

family.setname(n);
family.setadress(a);
family.setphone(p);
family.setage(g);

cout<<"my name"<<my.getname()<<endl;
cout<<"my address"<<my.getadress()<<endl;
cout<<"my phone"<<my.getphone()<<endl;
cout<<"my age"<<my.getage()<<endl;

// more cout statements with objects.getData ... 
return 0; 
}
```

Sorry for the long piece of code, I'm stuck and can't figure out what the issues are. 
Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use integers to store phone-numbers. Integers don't store leading zeros, but leading zeros are significant for phone-numbers.

Comment: As for your problem, can you please edit your question to include some specific input, and the expected and actual output?

Comment: Hint: think of what happens with the newline terminating input when you do the first `cin >> g;`, and what is next in the stream when the next `getline(cin, n);` executes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't have the means at this very moment to run the code on the current system. But the output basically skips the input step and goes to the next statement. (I will add it later tonight).

Comment: @SHR does that mean I have to add that to ignore the white space since getline doesn't use it as a delimiter? also why would the code change so drastically with the "relocation"of the declaration of the second, and third object?

Comment: when you use `cin>>` it stops at the first whitespace, therefore it won't read spaces line feeds etc. when using `getline` you get also white spaces till the '\n', so you need to eat the whitespaces (will always be a '\n' after `cin>>`, but maybe there is more input) before the first `getline` anytime you change input from `cin>>` to `getline`

Comment: `while(iswspace(cin.peek()))cin.ignore();` will eat the white spaces. in some old version of streams there was the `eatwhite` method for this.